# How to establish a relationship between three tables in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table that I don't have a direct relationship with from the model I am currently using.

My data structure:

Table: **posts**

- id - integer
- title - string

---

Table: **post_stacks**

- id - integer
- post_id - integer
- stack_id - integer

---

Table: **stacks**

- id - integer
- body - string
- url - string

---

My eloquent model is from the Post.php (posts table) and i'm trying to get all the stacks associated to my post (from the stacks table). I want to declare my relationships only on Post.php and not my pivot table (post_stacks).

I have tried `hasManyThrough` but the structure of my tables do not "fit" the requirements as Laravel requires as I need a foreign key on my Stacks table.

Here is my current implementation:

**Post.php**

```html
class Post extends Model
{

    protected $dates = [
      'created_at',
      'updated_at'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function post_stacks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\PostStack::class);
    }

    public function post_os()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\PostOS::class, 'post_id', 'id');
    }

    public function post_tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\PostTag::class , 'post_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->toFormattedDateString();
    }

}
```

**PostController.php**

```html
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        foreach($posts as $post){
            $post->user;
            $post->created_at;
            $posts_os = $post->post_os;
            $post_stacks = $post->post_stacks;
            $post_tags = $post->post_tags;

            foreach($posts_os as $post_os){
                $os = OS::where('id', $post_os->os_id)->first();
                $post_os['body'] = $os['body'];
            }

            foreach($post_stacks as $post_stack){
                $stack = Stack::where('id', $post_stack->stack_id)->first();
                $post_stack['url'] = $stack['url'];
                $post_stack['body'] = $stack['body'];
            }

            foreach($post_tags as $post_tag){
                $tag = Tag::where('id', $post_tag->tag_id)->first();
                $post_tag['body'] = $tag['body'];
            }
        }

        return response()->json($posts);
    }

}
```

**My JSON data response**

```js
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "title":"Laravel + XAMPP",
      "user_id":1,
      "description":"I'll take you through the entire process of setting up a development environment for Laravel using XAMPP.",
      "created_at":"Jun 12, 2017",
      "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
      "user":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"EpIEhg7ciO",
         "email":"AiyZXrubVG@gmail.com",
         "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
         "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02"
      },
      "post_os":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "post_id":1,
            "os_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"Windows"
         }
      ],
      "post_stacks":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "post_id":1,
            "stack_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "url":"laravel.svg",
            "body":"Laravel"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "post_id":1,
            "stack_id":2,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "url":"xampp.svg",
            "body":"XAMPP"
         }
      ],
      "post_tags":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "post_id":1,
            "tag_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"laravel"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "post_id":1,
            "tag_id":2,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"xampp"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "title":"Laravel + Vagrant",
      "user_id":1,
      "description":"I'll take you through the entire process of setting up a development environment for Laravel using Vagrant.",
      "created_at":"Jun 12, 2017",
      "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
      "user":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"EpIEhg7ciO",
         "email":"AiyZXrubVG@gmail.com",
         "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
         "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02"
      },
      "post_os":[  
         {  
            "id":2,
            "post_id":2,
            "os_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"Windows"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "post_id":2,
            "os_id":2,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"Mac OS X"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "post_id":2,
            "os_id":3,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"Linux"
         }
      ],
      "post_stacks":[  
         {  
            "id":3,
            "post_id":2,
            "stack_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "url":"laravel.svg",
            "body":"Laravel"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "post_id":2,
            "stack_id":3,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "url":"vagrant.png",
            "body":"Vagrant"
         }
      ],
      "post_tags":[  
         {  
            "id":3,
            "post_id":2,
            "tag_id":1,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"laravel"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "post_id":2,
            "tag_id":3,
            "created_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-12 08:55:02",
            "body":"vagrant"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My JSON data is exactly how i want it. I just think my PostController implementation is inefficient and runs too many queries. I am running too many queries and having nested loops. Is there a clean way I can establish a relationship using one of Laravel's methods/relationships?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you declare relations on the Stack model? You only ruled out adding relationships on the pivot table. If so:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function stacks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Stack::class);
    }
}

class Stack extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Post::class);
    }
}
```

By the fields defined in PostStack model, this should be all you need for Eloquent to make the relationship work. Additionally, you have access to the `pivot` property, allowing you to:

```
$post->pivot->somePropertyOnStack
```

**edit**

Excerpt from the docs to give you a general idea of how eloquent determines relationships:

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the  Comment model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id. So, for this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the Comment model is post_id.

And for relationships with joining tables:

> to determine the table name of the relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order.

This section of the docs will explain each relationship type and how Eloquent happens them:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: I don't quite understand, how are you relating those two models? there is no foreign key to establish a relationship?

Comment: Through the table names and the fields you have defined. Eloquent will assume some conventions about relations between tables when you add them to model classes.

Comment: Keep in mind, this ONLY works because of your intermediate table name  it's field names. They follow exactly what eloquent expects, so you don't need to "instruct" eloquent on how to make the relationships.